# How to delete a Redis key on disk?

Tags: java, redis, key, disk, del

I'm  newbie with Redis, I tried to delete a key on Ram done, but it has been existed on disk in dumb file. After restart server, the key on Ram has been existed. Please help me. How to sync data between ram and disk?

Comment: please help me, I don't know why doesn't it working.
here is my config file-redis.windows-service.conf ( http://www.mediafire.com/view/89o0ff9df8bb0bb/redis.windows-service.conf)  
and redis.windows.conf (http://www.mediafire.com/view/3rhdxkdo9i1l6l8/redis.windows%282%29.conf)

Answer (score 1):

depending on your config file, you can modify your `redis config file`, such as

```
appendonly yes
appendfsync always
# appendfsync everysec
# append
```

hope that helped.

Comment: I has just config such as u suggested, but it's don't working.
please help me, below is my config file. Has it any wrong?

[link file config](http://www.mediafire.com/view/k03ckybn2yvb6j2/redis.windows.conf)

Comment: redis-server  <redis.windows.conf path>

Comment: the file I attached is <redis.windows.conf>. Could you help me to find anything which I config wrong?

Comment: check whether exists appendonly.aof

Answer (score 1):

```
appendonly yes
appendfsync always
# appendfsync everysec
# append
```

do like above as Javy said surely is gonna help, this enable the aof and make sure data in ram were synced to disk every second.
Another way is issue a BGSAVE command to produce a new dump.rdb file right now. I think you should modify the frequency at which the automatic dump execute. This is in the redis.conf. See the item save.

Guess I'd better post the relative paragraph out for you:

```
################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################
#
# Save the DB on disk:
#
#   save <seconds> <changes>
#
#   Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
#   number of write operations against the DB occurred.
#
#   In the example below the behaviour will be to save:
#   after 900 sec (15 min) if at least 1 key changed
#   after 300 sec (5 min) if at least 10 keys changed
#   after 60 sec if at least 10000 keys changed
#
#   Note: you can disable saving completely by commenting out all "save" lines.
#
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
#   like in the following example:
#
#   save ""
```

If you donot know how to change the config file, type the following command in the specified order:

```
config set appendonly yes
config set appendonly everysec
config rewrite
```

If there's anything unclear, feel free to reply.

Comment: I has just config such as u suggested, but it's don't working. please help me, below is my config file. Has it any wrong?
[link file config](http://www.mediafire.com/view/k03ckybn2yvb6j2/redis.windows.conf)

Comment: your conf file is ok, but you may shoud change "appendfsync always
" to "appendfsync everysec" to enable your redis to run faster.

Comment: I think the problem may lie in how you restart your redis server. Can you show me the exact command you used to restart and start your redis?

Comment: @NothingintheWorld reply me if you see

Comment: I don't use any command to start and restart my redis. I only clicked at  redis-server.exe and closed it. Did i do anything wrong?

Comment: That's ok. Then type command `config get append*` in your redis server and show me the result @NothingintheWorld

Comment: [this is my config picture]http://i.imgur.com/etSjHyM.png
I can't command in redis server, that is command in redis client. . Could you help me config auto save on disk? Thanks you a lot.

Comment: type `config set appendonly yes` and then command `config rewrite` in redis client, then you won't lost data after restart.

Comment: how can I delete some data on disk?

Comment: Do as I said, and everything you deleted in redis-cli, will be deleted on disk

Comment: I get error when type:  config rewrite
(error) ERR The server is running without a config file

Comment: Then that's the problem. You should pass in a config file when you launch your redis. I never used windows redis, you can google about how to assign a particular redis.conf file when lauch redis